# Audience in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, audience-targeting, 2016

Can we control content using Audience in SharePoint 2016?

Use case : I want to display List content using Content Query webpart.

But all content will not be visible to all users.

Can we control this using Audience in SharePoint 2016?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question

Comment: Is Audience functionality supports in sharepoint 2016

Comment: Yes it is there.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, Audience Targeting is supported in SharePoint 2016 because it is not a deprecated feature *(see list of deprecated features here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346112(v=office.16).aspx).*

There are also no announced changes to how Audiences work so documentation for SharePoint 2013 Audience configuration and targeting will still apply. In most cases, the 2010 documentation will as well.