# Quick Launch and Audience in SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, audience-targeting, audiences

I found [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185209/audience-in-sharepoint-2016) that indicates that one can still use an Audience in SharePoint 2016 to target certain links in the Quick Launch. However, I do not see where I can do that and I can't figure it out. There are no settings for an audience in my site features or site collection features.

How can I use an audience to hide certain links in my Quick Launch bar in SharePoint 2016?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audience targeting for Quick Launch is only supported for site collections that have the Publishing Features enabled.